# python Popen.wait() daedlock on multiple pipes - why?

Tags: python, linux, unix, operating-system, pipe

Following code finishes correctly,

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("cat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
print p.returncode
```

but following code never end.

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen("cat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen("cat", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdin.close()
p1.wait()
p2.stdin.close()
p2.wait()

print p1.returncode, p2.returncode
```

The [doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) says,

> Warning This will deadlock if the child process generates enough
>   output to a stdout or stderr pipe such that it blocks waiting for the
>   OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use communicate() to avoid that.

but in this case, no output is generated.
Why it deadlocks?

I'm using Linux, and tried both python2.5 and 2.6.

--

edit

I also tried python2.7.1 and 3.2.3 on MacOSX. The results as follows

- 2.5.2(linux) -> deadlock
- 2.6.6(linux) -> deadlock
- 2.7.1(osx) -> daedlock
- 3.2.3(osx) -> ok!

Is this a bug in older python? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Works fine for me on `2.7.3`.  Did you mean to have some interaction between p1 and p2, because they seem to be completely decoupled in your example ..

Comment: I'm using Popen for parallelization. In my application, p1 and p2 do some heavy task reading from stdin instead of "cat".

Comment: Then you are going to need to use `communicate()`, as the docs mentioned ..   else the stdin pipe will block up!

Comment: I also tried communicate(), but it didn't change the result...

Comment: That code works fine. If you have a problem then post some code that shows the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finnaly, I noticed the answer by myself.

`close_fds=True` is needed to call Popen().
Because Popen does `pipe(2)` and `fork(2)`, not only parent process but also child process must close output side of the pipe.
On only newer python, close_fds=True seems to be default.

Thanks anyway ;)